# Handling html date input with Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to just send a date via a html form to a servlet, then send the date back to a jsp and display the date. I'm unsure of how to handle the date sent from the form. It seems to be an object, I tried casting it to a String but that returns null. I tried using the toString method of the date object but that did not work etiher.

```
java.sql.Date date = (java.sql.Date) request.getAttribute("date");
request.setAttribute("date", date.toString());

request.getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I want to do something like that, I need the date in sql date format. How do i achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're getting null, the attribute doesn't exist. But I suspect you're looking for `getParameter()`.

Comment: Oh yes that worked. It was a String after all. Thanks for that.

Comment: Its not in the format I wanted though

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Comment: I'm sure I can reformat it to how I want it. Thanks for your help

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing looks weird in your code is the use of java.sql.Date. That class is used in JDBC API to interact with databases, it is more common using java.util.Date, or for JDK 8+, you should use java.time.LocalDate.
After that said, lets go specifically to your issue, you should use in your servlet instead of getAttribute, getParameter, like that:

```
 String date = request.getParameter("date");
```

Then send it to the JSP:

```
request.setAttribute("date", date);
```

I hope that help you out,

Cheers,

-Rod